# JsTree speed issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have a page that contains 8 jstree's, 3 of which are very large.

The obvious problem is that the page take 13 seconds to load, which is crap.
Through profiling I know this is all jstree processing time.

Does anyone have any ideas on reducing page load times ?

I was thinking partial loading of elements but this will be a downer on user experience.

Thanks, Alex

Comment: Seems to me that user experience on a page with **8** tree widgets is in serious peril to begin with.

Comment: it is a tabbed page so does not actually show 8 trees all at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a tabbed page, why not just load the trees when the specific tab is selected?

Other than that, the next best way is partial loading **or** building multiple json string on server load and storing them in an array client side - then build the trees without making additional server calls.